# Can't deploy nodejs app to heroku and openshift

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, npm, openshift

I can't deploy my ExpressJS app to Heroku or OpenShift hosting. On my MacBook Pro all works perfectly, but it go to crash when I try to deploy it on hosting.

`error Error: shasum check failed for /app/tmp/npm-403-gj-8PMyB/1387967953013-0.7812028499320149/tmp.tgz
344 error Expected: f99cd60b91df7e6669c59ac2b55c4bfc65ff9494
344 error Actual:   c4a5f6cf7f807d89d1aa0babe686b434426206b6`

[openshift log](https://dpaste.de/Vd7V#L), [heroku log](https://dpaste.de/wef7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on Heroku before that I did not figure out what caused it.But this is how I fixed mine:

first remove the dependency (in your case it could be process-pwd ) from package.json file
open the terminal app on your mac and go to you project folder
run the install command for the package that fails

```
npm install moduleName
```

this will install a local copy of the module in your project folder inside node_modules folder

deploy the app again

Hope this works but you have to figure out which module actually fails :)

Comment: I removed all of node_modules gitignore. Then I posted it all on heroku, and it worked! Thank you!